# WordPress: How can i convert all post from sport category to news category by sql

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

How can convert all posts that in category sport into news category by using SQL statement, Because i have more than 2000 posts

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I still try but not work yet

Comment: As in nothing is updated or it says there is an error with the query?

Answer (score 1):

This should work*,

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = '3' WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '1';
```

Where `1` is the id of the News category and `3` is the id of the Sports category

***You should back up your tables before making this change just in case something goes wrong.**