# Wordpress: How to change category for posts. (about 30000 posts)

Tags: wordpress

We have about 30000 posts. we need to change category of them to "news category". How can I change them? Should I do on database? if so, which fields I need to update?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [WordPress: How can i convert all post from sport category to news category by sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495138/wordpress-how-can-i-convert-all-post-from-sport-category-to-news-category-by-sq)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin which allows you to do that although it will still take some time as it is still limited to what you can select on the screen each time.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/batchmove/

Updating the database could be much quicker but it depends on the scope of the changes - how many you need to change (ie. do you want to change all posts or just some), what the posts you want to change have in common (are you going from category A to category B which is pretty easy but if they are all currently in mixed categories and you want to change to category B less so) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a query for the posts and then use [wp_set_post_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories). Something like the following can be done:

```
$args = array(
    'category' => CURRENT_CATEGORY_ID,
);
$posts_to_change = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts_to_change as $post ) {
    wp_set_post_categories( $post->ID, array(NEW_CATEGORY_ID) );
}
```